# PowerShell Error, Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, powershell

i have typed the following inside PowerShell:-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Restore-spsite ?

cmdlet Restore-SPSite at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path: "C:\Users\m.g\Desktop\Backup\Intranet"

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation "Restore-SPSite" on Target "?".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):y
```

**But power shell will raise the following exception**,

> Restore-spsite : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be
>   determined. At line:1 char:1
>   + Restore-spsite ?
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:    SPCmdletRestoreSite)
>   [Restore-SPSite], UriFormatException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS    ite

If i understand the error right, power shell is unable to understand the following path `C:\Users\m.g\Desktop\Backup\Intranet` which contain the backup file, is that right ? and if yes then why power shell did not understand this path ??
Thanks

Comment: What is the point of the ? you type after the cmdlet?

Comment: trying to get help on the command?

Answer (score 2):

Restore-SPSite will require two parameters

- Identity - your site collection url
- Path -backup path of site you wanted to restore (full file path till .bak)

Comment: Also add "-Force" attribute

Answer (score 0):

There might be a lot of point where you probably making mistake.

Check possible reasons could be here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to provide the site that you're restoring to with your command line. So, for example, if you were restoring to `http://intranet/sites` then your command would look like:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> Restore-spsite `http://intranet/sites`

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to restore to a host header web application?

if so use:

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication <your webapp>
Restore-SPSite -Identity <URL of sitecol> -Path <path to backup> -HostHeaderWebApplication $w.Url
```